# Create new related entity and enter its id into a link table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

My `foo`s each have a `bar`.

At least they're supposed to.

I now want to create and assign `bar`s to all `foo`s that don't.

`bar` is completely detached from `foo`, it only has an `id` serial that serves as its primary key

```sql
CREATE TABLE bar
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

`bar`s are attached to `foo`s by use of a `foo_bar` link table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo_bar
(
    foo_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT foo_bar__foo__fk
            REFERENCES foo
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
    bar_id  INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT foo_bar__bar__fk
            REFERENCES bar
            ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT foo_bar__pk
        PRIMARY KEY (foo_id, bar_id)
);
```

my first attempt

```sql
WITH
foos_without_bar AS (
    SELECT f.id
    FROM foo f
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
            FROM foo_bar fb
            WHERE fb.foo_id = f.id
    )
),
new_bars AS (
    INSERT INTO bar(id)
        SELECT DEFAULT
        FROM foos_without_bar f
        RETURNING f.id as foo_id, bar.id as bar_id
)
INSERT INTO foo_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
    SELECT n.foo_id, n.bar_id
    FROM new_bars n
;
```

fails with

```
ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context
LINE 13:         SELECT DEFAULT
                        ^
```

and my second using `nextval`:

```sql
WITH
foos_without_bar AS (
    SELECT f.id
    FROM foo f
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
            FROM foo_bar fb
            WHERE fb.foo_id = f.id
    )
),
new_bars AS (
    INSERT INTO bar(id)
        SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('bar','id'))
        FROM foos_without_bar f
        RETURNING f.id as foo_id, bar.id as bar_id
)
INSERT INTO foo_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
    SELECT n.foo_id, n.bar_id
    FROM new_bars n
;
```

also fails, this time because

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "f"
LINE 15:         RETURNING f.id as foo_id, bar.id as bar_...
                           ^
```

and I'm not quite sure how to rectify that.

How do I make this statement work?

Comment: what is the structure of foo ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi Well, it has an integer `id` and some more fields that are not related to the question?

Comment: I would use a cursor for this

Comment: I need it to simulate the same code you provided. Can you share an input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and decided to just write a function:

```sql
DO $createMissingBars$
DECLARE
    new_bar_id INTEGER;
    foos_without_bar INTEGER[];
BEGIN
    foos_without_bar := ARRAY (
        SELECT f.id
        FROM foo f
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM foo_bar fb
            WHERE fb.foo_id = f.id
        )
    );

    FOR i in 1 .. array_upper(foos_without_bar,1) LOOP
        INSERT INTO foo_bar
            DEFAULT VALUES
            RETURNING bar.id INTO new_bar_id
        ;
        INSERT INTO foo_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
            VALUES (foos_without_bar[i], new_bar_id)
        ;
    END LOOP;
END $createMissingBars$;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your explaination, I think that you want to create a new bar for every foo that doesn't have one, and then create an entry in the foo_bar table to link the foo and its new bar.

There's a problem with the way you're trying to insert rows into bar and return the corresponding foo_id from foos_without_bar. The RETURNING clause can only return values that were actually inserted into the table.

You can solve this by first generating bar for each foo in foos_without_bar and then inserting the links in foo_bar.

If that's what you want try below query,

```
WITH
foos_without_bar AS (
    SELECT f.id
    FROM foo f
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM foo_bar fb
        WHERE fb.foo_id = f.id
    )
),
new_bars AS (
    INSERT INTO bar(id)
        SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('bar','id'))
        FROM foos_without_bar
        RETURNING id as bar_id
),
foo_bar AS (
    SELECT f.id as foo_id, nb.bar_id
    FROM foos_without_bar f
    JOIN new_bars nb ON TRUE
)
INSERT INTO foo_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
    SELECT fb.foo_id, fb.bar_id
    FROM foo_bar fb
;
```

The `JOIN ON TRUE` operation in the `foo_bar` subquery pairs each foo in `foos_without_bar` with each bar in `new_bars`. Since there is the same number of foo and bar (one bar for each foo), each foo is matched with the bar that corresponds to it by order.

Be aware that this operation assumes that `foos_without_bar` and `new_bars` return rows in the same order. Normally, this should be the case, but it's not guaranteed by SQL standards, and might not be true if your actual query is more complex than the provided example.

As a final note, remember to be careful with concurrency issues. If this code is running while other code might be modifying the `foo`, `bar`, or `foo_bar` tables, there could be race conditions. Consider using appropriate locking mechanisms if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, but this suffers from the same issue the (now deleted) answer using a `CROSS JOIN` had: `JOIN new_bars nb ON TRUE` returns a new record for each `foo` that didn't have a `bar` before, FOR EACH NEW `bar` CREATED! You'd be assigning all of the new `bar`s to each `foo` that was lacking one, which is completely wrong.